# Report deployment on JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, subreport

I have created a master report along with a sub report.

I run the report in *iReport*, it works well. I deployed it on *JR Server* and added the *subreport* in Resorces folder. Also I changed the subreport expression value. When I run the report through the jasper server, following error occurs:

`1 - net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error opening input stream from URL : repo:emp_count_subrep.jrxml`

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Check the xml source, you will find subreport reference to the .jasper file, just change the extension to jrxml and ti will work, at least it worked for me